# C programming elementary problem

Tags: c, dev-c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main (void)
{
    float inches;
    printf("Enter the number of inches\n");
    scanf("%f\n",&inches);


    float feet;
    float cm;
    float yards;
    float meter;

    feet = 12 * inches;
    cm = 2.54 * inches;
    yards = 36 * inches;
    meter = 39.37 * inches;

    printf("Amount in feet: %f\n", &feet);
    printf("Amount in cm:   %f\n", &cm);
    printf("Amount in yards: %f\n", &yards);
    printf("Amount in meters: %f\n", &meter);




   getchar();

   return 0;

}
```

I'm using Dev c++

Is the problem i'm problem I'm working on in C. Basically enter in a number in inches then print amount in cm,yards,meters and feet. This is giving me 0.0000 or something for all of them or actually the time it is up. I can't keep the screen up and I thought that was the purpose of getchar() but I must have been mistaken. Any help is great. Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

What about as far as keeping dev c++ on the screen instead of closing out after I put stuff in? I am also having to put 2 values in before it returns in anything when the screen pops up? Why??

Comment: Others have addressed your problem, but as a side note: `feet = inches / 12.0; yards = inches / 36.0; meters = inches / 39.37;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The usual problem with using `scanf()`, in that it leaves the newline after the number unread and the following read operation (the `getchar()` here) reads it.
2. You shouldn't pass pointers to `printf()`, but the actual values.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to print the addresses of your floats as floats, you just want to say this:

```
printf("Amount in feet: %f\n", feet);
```

Note the lack of an address (`&`) operator on `feet`. You want to apply similar changes to your other [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) calls.

Comment: What about as far as keeping dev c++ on the screen instead of closing out after I put stuff in? I am also having to put 2 values in before it returns in anything when the screen pops up? Why???

Comment: @er31: Sorry, I don't know anything about Dev C++.

Comment: I suggest not to use Dev-C++ GUI to run console program; run them from a command line. Moreover, I hope you're using a separate installation of MinGW since the one given in bundle with Dev-C++ is very old

Answer (score 0):

With `printf`, you don't give it the address of the `float` values, you just give it the values. Remove the `&`s from the `printf` calls.

You need the address in `scanf` because the function modifies the variables that you pass in, but `printf` just needs the values. As it is, the `printf` is essentially reinterpreting the pointers as floats, which is why you get the garbage values displayed.

Answer (score 0):

About *I can't keep the screen up*, it's a common problem to everyone trying to execute a console program in a graphical environment directly from the IDE, in particular Dev-C++. The problem is that there's no console for I/O, then one is provided but just for the time the program is running, and since programs are fast, if you do not add a pause after your last input and output, you won't have the time to read the output.

Many MS Windows Dev-C++ users add an horrorific `system("pause")`. I always suggest that, if Dev-C++ is not able to provide a console for I/O with the option "keep it opened even after the program ends", then it is better you open a shell (cmd or powershell on windows) and run your program directly from there.

About the input problem, unluckly scanf-ing has several buffering problem since the input that is not recognized for the given format is not discarded and is ready for the next reading. E.g.

```
scanf("%f", &aFloat);
scanf("%f", &theNextFloat); // in your case you have the extra getchar();
```

won't stop for the second scanf if you write `1.25 4.5` as first input, since the `4.5` is already available for the next scanf. In your case it was a newline that was left in the buffer and since getchar has found it, it does not need to wait for input. You could use a 
`while( getchar() != EOF ) ;` instead, and then to exit you need to hit Ctrl-D.

Comment: someone told me it is Ctrl-Z on windows, not Ctrl-D; I haven't verified it, but I suppose it's true